# Three.js with Angular: Object not visible in Scene

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, three.js, 3d

I am trying to render a 3d-model in my web using Three.js.
(I am trying to make a Pokédex :) )
The projekt uses ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Angular 7.
The model is an FBX-file, thus I am using the FBX-Loader.

The problem is: I cannot seem to see the model.

What I've tried:

- Check if the model is loaded correctly by the fbx loader
- Check if the models binary format is supported by Three.js
- Check if the scene actually contains the model after adding
- Check if the camera is looking at the scene
- Check if the camera is inside the model
- Check if the normals are inverted
- Add Light to the Scene
- Check if the model is visible on another browser (FF, Chrome, Edge)
- Try to code according to the documentation
- Try to load another format (.dae, using Collada-loader)
- Of course checked the console output thoroughly

The relevant code is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Pokemon } from "../models/pokemon";
import { mockPokemon } from "../../mockdata/mockPokemon";
import { Type } from "../models/type";
import { FBXService } from "../services/fbx-service";
var THREE = require('three');
var FBXLoader = require('three-fbx-loader');

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var loader = new FBXLoader();
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: false });
renderer.setSize(500, 500);
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, 1, 0, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, -500, 0);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

@Component({
    selector: 'app-pokemon-list',
    templateUrl: './pokemon-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./pokemon-list.component.scss']
})
export class PokemonListComponent {

public pokemon: Pokemon;
public nationalDexId = "";

constructor(private fbxService: FBXService) {
    this.pokemon = mockPokemon[0];
    this.setUpManager();
    this.getFBX();
    this.renderFBX();
}

setUpManager() {
    manager.onStart = function (fbx, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal) {
        console.log('Started loading file: ' + fbx + '\nLoaded ' +  itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files')
    }
    manager.onLoad = function () {
        console.log('Loading complete!');
    };
    manager.onProgress = function (fbx, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal) {

        console.log('Loading file: ' + fbx + '\nLoaded ' + itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files');

    };
    manager.onError = function (fbx) {

        console.log('There was an error loading ' + fbx);
    };

    loader = new FBXLoader(manager);
}

getFBX(): void {

    var fbx = this.fbxService.getFBX(this.pokemon.nameEn);

    loader.load(fbx,
        function (object3d) {
            var mesh = object3d.children[2];
            mesh.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
            scene.add(mesh)
        },
        function (progress) {
            console.log("Status: " + progress.explicitOriginalTarget.statusText);
            console.log(progress);
        }
    );

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

renderFBX() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.renderFBX);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    console.log(scene);
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

So now I am passing the mesh from my loader inside the setContent function:

```
setContent(object: any): void {
        object.updateMatrixWorld();
        const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
        const size = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
        const center = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

        camera.near = size / 100;
        camera.far = size * 100;
        camera.fov = size;
        camera.aspect = 1;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        camera.position.copy(center);
        camera.position.x += size * 2;
        camera.position.y += size * 2;
        camera.position.z += size * 2;
        camera.lookAt(center);
        scene.add(object);
        console.log(scene);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

So I've created a Bounding-Box to configure my camera from according to Mugen87 in the comment section.
The camera should now be outside of the bounding-box (and hence outside of the model) and pointing towards the center.
As you can see, the scene position is at (0,0,0) and the camera-position is approx. at (692, 692, 692):

[Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgfcC.png)
[Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiXN9.png)

I still can't see the model. What other factors are significant here?
Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: Can you load your FBX at other viewers like [Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com)? Besides, you can try to automatically set optimal configuration values of the camera based on the bounding box of your model. Check out the code of the following viewer to see how this works: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/master/src/viewer.js#L218-L246

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Yes, I could upload it at sketchfab: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/cube-7fa7949ab05d4b14ad2eb753e748b6e1 (just a test cube)
I will try to set the configuration for the camera as you suggested and tell what I could figure out!

Comment: Hello again!
So I tried to fit the code into my environment and got pretty far, but now I am stuck on THREE.Box3 not having a property "position". It only contains a min- and a max-vector property, and I am unsure which (if even) to use

Comment: Um, you acutally don't have to use these properties. You just compute the AABB via `Box3.setFromObject()` and then use the size and center vectors for further processing.

Comment: Ahh right, I think no I am getting where this is going. So I removed that part of the code (I will post it in an Update). I also noticed that my loader is not returning an object3d, but a group instead. Inside the group is a mesh (which is an extension of object3d if I am not mistaken). Does this make a difference for the bounding box?

Comment: No. It can handle such use cases.